# GAE Datastore Permission Denied?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

I'm trying to learn how to use Google App Engine, and I'm using the QuickStart documentation for Python [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app). It's a simple code to write timestamps to a datastore, and then print them back to the user.

I'm following the code and steps fairly strictly, but I'm using the Cloud Shell and Cloud Console instead of downloading the SDK and running the code locally.

The first half of the code works perfectly, and I'm able to deploy the web service. When I start using the datastore, however, I get a `500 Internal Server Error` in my app. The full `main.py` is provided below. I commented out sections of the code and figured out that the issue seems to come when writing to the datastore. The error log shows a `PERMISSION DENIED` error (log below).

From what I can see, using the Cloud Shell should mean that the authentication between my python script and the datastore should "just work", but it looks like it doesn't. I'm also using the exact code from Google's documentation, so I don't get why it should get an error.

Any ideas on what I might try?

Here's my `main.py`:

```
import datetime

from flask import Flask, render_template

from google.cloud import datastore

datastore_client = datastore.Client()

app = Flask(__name__)


def store_time(dt):
    entity = datastore.Entity(key=datastore_client.key('visit'))
    entity.update({
       'timestamp': dt
    })

    datastore_client.put(entity)


def fetch_times(limit):
    query = datastore_client.query(kind='visit')
    query.order = ['-timestamp']
    times = query.fetch(limit=limit)

    return times


@app.route('/')
def root():
    store_time(datetime.datetime.now())

    times = fetch_times(10)

    return render_template(
        'index.html', times=times)
```

The error log shows the following error:

> File "", line 3, in raise_from:
>   google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Missing or
>   insufficient permissions. at error_remapped_callable
>   (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py:59)
>   at func_with_timeout
>   (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py:214) at
>   retry_target
>   (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py:184) at
>   retry_wrapped_func
>   (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py:286) at
>   **call** (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py:143)
>   at commit
>   (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore_v1/gapic/datastore_client.py:571)
>   at _commit
>   (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/batch.py:250)
>   at commit
>   (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/batch.py:274)
>   at put_multi
>   (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/client.py:490)
>   at put
>   (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/client.py:463)
>   at store_time (/srv/main.py:20) at root (/srv/main.py:36) at
>   dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1935)
>   at full_dispatch_request
>   (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1949) at reraise
>   (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py:39) at
>   handle_user_exception
>   (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1820) at
>   full_dispatch_request
>   (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1951) at wsgi_app
>   (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:2446)

Comment: please add the `app.yaml` and `requirements.txt`

Comment: minor: convention is to capitalize the first letter of Datastore kinds. So `Visit` rather than `visit`

Comment: App Engine access to Datastore is controlled by the permissions on your project's [default App Engine service account](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/service-account). Check that this service account has a role that can access Datastore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Cloud Shell and took your code as-is. Your code works for me.

Created:

```sh
PROJECT=[[YOUR-PROJECT]]
REGION=[[YOUR-REGION]] # us-west2
gcloud app create --project=${PROJECT} --region=${REGION}
```

With:

`app.yaml`:

```
runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

> **NB** `entrypoint` is optional but I prefer to be explicit

`requirements.txt`:

```
Flask==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
google-cloud-datastore==1.12.0
```

and used the exemplar template:

`templates/index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h2>Visits:</h2>
  {% for time in times %}
    <p>{{ time }}</p>
  {% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

And:

```sh
gcloud app deploy app.yaml --project=${PROJECT}
```

Then browsing the app's endpoint:

```
Visits:

<Entity('visit', 5079418695319552) {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 12, 20, 20, 29, 417656, tzinfo=<UTC>)}>
<Entity('visit', 5702893864747008) {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 12, 20, 16, 28, 305081, tzinfo=<UTC>)}>
<Entity('visit', 5636645067948032) {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 12, 20, 16, 26, 495333, tzinfo=<UTC>)}>
<Entity('visit', 5642368648740864) {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 12, 20, 16, 22, 369022, tzinfo=<UTC>)}>
<Entity('visit', 5632499082330112) {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 12, 20, 16, 20, 659993, tzinfo=<UTC>)}>
```

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin. For some reason, this did not work in the project that I already had (even after making the changes you suggested), but the moment I created a new project and deployed that, it worked like a charm